# How To Change Column Names of Data Frames In A List

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list of data frames and want to change **part** of column name of each of the sub data frame this list holds.

```
list(A = structure(list(`A-DIODE` = c(1.2, 0.4), `A-DIODE` = c(1.3, 
0.6)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame"), B = structure(list(
    `B-DIODE` = c(1.4, 0.8), `B-ACC1` = c(1.5, 1), `B-ACC2` = c(1.6, 
    1.2), `B-ANA0` = c(1.7, 1.4), `B-ANA1` = c(1.8, 1.6), `B-BRICKID` = c(1.9, 
    1.8), `B-CC0` = c(2L, 2L), `B-CC1` = c(2.1, 2.2), `B-DIGDN` = c(2.2, 
    2.4), `B-DIGDP` = c(2.3, 2.6), `B-DN1` = c(2.4, 2.8), `B-DN2` = c(2.5, 
    3), `B-DP1` = c(2.6, 3.2), `B-DP2` = c(2.7, 3.4), `B-SCL` = c(2.8, 
    3.6), `B-SDA` = c(2.9, 3.8), `B-USB0DN` = 3:4, `B-USB0DP` = c(3.1, 
    4.2), `B-USB1DN` = c(3.2, 4.4), `B-USB1DP` = c(3.3, 4.6), 
    `B-ACC1` = c(3.4, 4.8), `B-ACC2` = c(3.5, 5), `B-ANA0` = c(3.6, 
    5.2), `B-ANA1` = c(3.7, 5.4), `B-BRICKID` = c(3.8, 5.6), 
    `B-CC0` = c(3.9, 5.8), `B-CC1` = c(4L, 6L), `B-DIGDN` = c(4.1, 
    6.2), `B-DIGDP` = c(4.2, 6.4), `B-DN1` = c(4.3, 6.6), `B-DN2` = c(4.4, 
    6.8), `B-DP1` = c(4.5, 7), `B-DP2` = c(4.6, 7.2), `B-SCL` = c(4.7, 
    7.4), `B-SDA` = c(4.8, 7.6), `B-USB0DN` = c(4.9, 7.8), `B-USB0DP` = c(5L, 
    8L), `B-USB1DN` = c(5.1, 8.2), `B-USB1DP` = c(5.2, 8.4), 
    `B-NA` = c(5.3, 8.6), `B-ACC2PWRLKG_0v4` = c(5.4, 8.8), `B-ACC2PWRLKG_0v4` = c(5.5, 
    9), `B-P_IN_Leak` = c(5.6, 9.2)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame"))
```

I want to change `A-` in above data frame in a list to `Z-` and then `B-` in another data frame in the list to `P-`.

I tired below code but it doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions on how I can do this?

```
names(data$`A-DIODE`) <- "Z-DIODE"
names(data$`B-DIODE`) <- "P-DIODE"
....
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `lapply()` with a vectorized function from the *stringi* package to do the replacement.

```
library(stringi)

lapply(x0, function(x) {
    out <- stri_replace_all_regex(names(x), c("^A-", "^B-"), c("Z-", "P-"), vectorize_all = FALSE)
    names(x) <- out
    x
})
```

Comment: .@RichScriven - Thank you. Is it also possible to change the data frame name that's referenced. For above data if I load it to a variable `sample_data` then I will reference `Z` as `sample_data$A$Z-DIODE`, is it possible to replace A in this case too?

Comment: @ChetanArvindPatil - yes, those are just the names of the list.  For that you simply use `names(sample_data) <- whatever you want`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the lapply function. lapply will allow you to change the names in each of dataframe in the list.

In your above example, lets name your list as data. A and B are the dataframes nested in your list. To change the column names for particular names in the dataframes in the list

```
data=lapply(data,function(x){
names(x)[which(names(x)=="A-DIODE")]="Z-DIODE"
names(x)[which(names(x)=="B-DIODE")]="P-DIODE"
x
}
)
```